# how i fetch record in list from one column of database seperated by space in php

Tags: php, mysql, listview, fetch

My question is that how can I fetch product_details column in list view on front end, on the base of space or comma?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get your question. but, i guess this is actually you want,

```
$array = "we deal in door, window, tables, carpets";

$arr = explode(",",$array);
echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
    }
echo "</ul>";
```

O/p will be:

- we deal in door
- window
- tables
- carpets

Hope this exactly you want.

greetings!

Comment: yes exactly like that thanks, now how do i fetch that row value in array.?

Comment: Have fun @Sikandar..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
$myString = "We deals in Doors,Windows,Tables,Carpets";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);

foreach($myArray as $value) //loop over values
{
    echo $value . '<br>'; 
}
```